# C# Remote MySQL - Access Denied For User

Tags: c#, mysql

I cannot seem to connect to my remote `MySQL` database using C#. When I use `MySQL Workbench` I am able to connect successfully. But when I connect via connection string with C# I get:

*Access denied for user 'username'@'myipaddress' to database 'drawingnumbers'*

My connection string:

```
  connectionString = "server=" + server + ";user=" + uid + ";database=" + database + ";port=" + port + ";password=" + password + ";";
```

What I have tried:

1. Added my local and external IP in the remote MySQL connection on cpanel
2. Granting permission to my username to connect remotely with some SQL command I found online, access was denied (This is a shared server)
3. Connected successfully using MySQL workbench with exact same parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using the username suffix in CPanel, because people miss that in most cases...
for example if your CPanel username was abc then it should be 
abc_TheUsernameForMySQL

if not, try your CPanel username and Password,
also you can use the ip address from the error to confirm you added the correct remote ip address to access the mysql server

Comment: Ah... There was my issue. I used suffix_mysqlusername BUT I didn't do the same for the database. You also need to do suffix_databasename. Thanks!

Comment: my apologies, forgot about the database as well