# "Access denied for user 'test'@'%' to database 'test'

Tags: c#, mysql, access-denied

I have been trying to access the remote `MySql` database server in `C# Entity framework`  but end in following error

`{"Access denied for user 'test'@'%' to database 'test'"}`

My connection string is `server='192.168.0.1';uid=test;database=test;password=1234`

However if i access the database through `workbench` it allows me to access the `server` and `inserting and deleting` the data in tables.

What causing the error ?

Comment: Check here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html if you're config match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Remote MySQL - Access Denied For User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242134/c-sharp-remote-mysql-access-denied-for-user)

Answer (score 1):

Execute below statement to grant access on test-

```
GRANT all privileges on test.* to test@'%' identified by '1234';
```

Note: You can change all privileges with your specific permissions.

You can also assign rights on all databases by-

```
GRANT all privileges on *.* to test@'%' identified by '1234';
```

Note: Best way is that rights should provide only to specific ip and limited rights as per requirement.

Comment: first connect mysql either from localhost or from any gui tool like sqlyog, mysqladmin, mysql workbench etc...but by which user you are connecting that user should have grant permissions so that can grant permission to other user...else you can ask your DBA who is managing your DB.